# Recommendation / Marrying Up Algorithm in PHP?

Tags: php

Is there something that has been already developed and is Open Sourced?

I'd like to develop a site that is like:

http://www.swap.com/

What I envisage is that a USER A puts in what they have, dvd's, book's, cd's, etc.

USER A then puts in what they are looking for themselves.

The system then does a check against all the users.  It finds that USER B is requesting items thats in USER A's inventory.

So USER A can swap item X for USER B item X.

I just don't want to try (operative word here being try) to reinvent the wheel if its kinda been done before.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm... not too hard to code, as dionyziz said it's a very simple SQL query. Since you don't want to recreate anything, I suggest looking into inventory scripts. These are scripts generally used to keep track of a store or business's inventory of items for sale, however if you find one that's designed to manage multiple "stores", then each "user" could be a store with their own "inventory".

A quick search for "open source php inventory script" turned up http://www.phpwares.com/

Not sure if it supports multiple "stores", though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I've got tables that recreate a users "inventory" but the question isn't really about this.  It's about finding the other users B, C, D, E that have items that user A wants and if there are any matches.  Also being listed in order of matches.

Comment: Any inventory software will have a way of checking the inventory for the existence of an item. Just use that routine for every user iteratively. A simple while loop can run the "check for item" function once per user.

Comment: Otherwise if you wanted to design your own then you could even make it better by having the search entirely on the MySQL side. But your question was for something pre-coded, not for the SQL structure you would use for such a query.

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done with an SQL query. SELECT from your whole userbase those items who match your currently logged in user's requests.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, having a look at swap.com they say they have a patented method for doing the swaps.  Surely there's more to just doing a simple select query?